# How do I disable the "by author" hyperlink on posts?

Tags: posts, templates, author

I'm trying to disable the "author" hyperlink when making a post, but having no success.

How can I do it?

[image]

Comment: It is going to depend on your theme, what theme are you using.  Also you can post images directly into your question without linking to a third-party site.

Comment: You need to edit your theme (preferably make a Child Theme), this is a starting point: https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+edit+a+wordpress+theme

Comment: @helgatheviking first time on this site. im using the zillapress theme from themeforest.

Comment: @ brasofilo yes i gathered that.....what do i need to edit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look for `single.php` in your theme directory. There you should find `the_author()`, you can remove that to remove a reference to the author.

You will be able to find all your answers [in the codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development), by the way.

Comment: ok, so the answer @Sunyatasattva gave worked, however when i view a category i and see all the posts, i the author links come back..........any ideas?

Comment: nvm, i figured it out in the category